# Different my name of layer ResNet50 and original ResNet50

Tags: python-3.x, keras, keras-layer, resnet, imagenet

I run this Code for use pretrained ResNet50 with ImageNet:

```
from keras.applications import ResNet50
conv_base = ResNet50()
print(conv_base.summary())
```

But, the name for each layer is not same with original ResNet50(access in internet).

---

### For example:

---

**My result: (Not Correcte)**

```
activation_95 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 5 0           bn5c_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5c_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, None, None, 5 2359808     activation_95[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5c_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, None, None, 5 2048        res5c_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_96 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 5 0           bn5c_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5c_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, None, None, 2 1050624     activation_96[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5c_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, None, None, 2 8192        res5c_branch2c[0][0]
```

**Original result: (Correcte)**

```
conv5_block3_1_bn (BatchNormali (None, 7, 7, 512)    2048        conv5_block3_1_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_1_relu (Activation (None, 7, 7, 512)    0           conv5_block3_1_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_2_conv (Conv2D)    (None, 7, 7, 512)    2359808     conv5_block3_1_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_2_bn (BatchNormali (None, 7, 7, 512)    2048        conv5_block3_2_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_2_relu (Activation (None, 7, 7, 512)    0           conv5_block3_2_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_3_conv (Conv2D)    (None, 7, 7, 2048)   1050624     conv5_block3_2_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_3_bn (BatchNormali (None, 7, 7, 2048)   8192        conv5_block3_3_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_add (Add)          (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           conv5_block2_out[0][0]           
                                                                 conv5_block3_3_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_out (Activation)   (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           conv5_block3_add[0][0]
```

install different version of python but not correct!

please help me.

Comment: Your import should result an error. Because ``ResNet50`` class not exist on keras.apllications module.!! Anyway Try ``from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50``

Answer (score 0):

I do this step and it corrected:

1. Uninstall anacoda-navigator.
2. Uninstall all version of python.
3. Download and Install python 3.7.0 form python website.
4. Install packages with Pip.
5. Install Cudatoolkit and Cudnn [(Help)](https://spltech.co.uk/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-5-with-cuda-11-2-and-cudnn-8-1-for-windows-10/)
6. Add Path to environmental variable [(Help)](https://spltech.co.uk/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-5-with-cuda-11-2-and-cudnn-8-1-for-windows-10/)

Thank a lot.